# change audio file sampling rate

Tags: matlab

I want to ask how can I change sampling rate for audio file in matlab R2016a??
the default is 44100 
I want to change it to 22050 
as shown in my code I am trying to convert sampling rate, but it doesn't work...

```
 clear;
 fs1 = 44100;
 fs2 = 22050;
 SRC = dsp.SampleRateConverter('InputSampleRate',fs1,'OutputSampleRate',fs2);
[Sa,SRC] = audioread('W_Sound_1.wav');  % Sa : All of sampling , Fs :Sampling rate
 sa_W = Sa;
audiowrite('W_Sound_1_resampling.wav',sa_W,SRC)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is that you don't use the `SampleRateConverter` object `SRC` anywhere. In fact, by using `SRC` as the second output argument of `audioread()`, you overwrite it with a number containing the current sample rate.

If you want to use `SampleRateConverter`, check out some examples [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.samplerateconverter-class.html).

But, it's probably simpler to use [resample()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html)

Comment: .... thanks for your answer, Its work with resample() ,, but after i use it ,how can i have the new audio ? what should i use to get the re-sampled audio ? .... this is my new code

Comment: clear;
x = audioread('W_Sound_1.wav');
y = resample(x,44100,22050);

Comment: @ReemR In your new code, `y` contains the resampled audio. You can write it to a file using `audiowrite()`.